# Activated plugin not showing in backend form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a wordpress newbie and I made a simple widget plugin that displays heading and text. Everything seems fine, the plugin is activated but the widget just doesn't show in the backend widget list. What am I doing wrong?

I've searched, checked and rechecked high and low but can't seem to pinpoint what is wrong.

Here's my code files:

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    function ms_init_widgets($id){
       register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Showcase',
            'id' => 'showcase',
            'before_widget'  => '',
            'after_widget' => '',
            'before_title' => '',
            'after_title' => ''
        ));
    }

add_action('widgets_init', 'ms_init_widgets');
```

**new-showcase-widget.php**

```
<?php
    /*
    *Plugin name:   New Showcase Widget
    *Description: A new showcase widget that displays a title and text
    *Author: Shefalizzle
    *version: 1.0
    *
    */

    include('class.new-showcase-widget.php');

    function register_new_showcase_widget(){
        register_widget('New_Showcase_Widget');
    }

    add_action('widgets-init', 'register_new_showcase_widget');
```

**class.new-showcase-widget.php**

```
<?php

class New_Showcase_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    // constructor
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 
            'classname' => 'new_showcase_widget',
            'description' => __('A new widget I created that is actually working', 'text_domain'),
        );
        parent::__construct( 'new_showcase_widget', 'New_Showcase_Widget', $widget_ops );
    }

    // widget form creation
    function form($instance) {  
    /* ... */
    if( $instance) {
     $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
     $heading = esc_attr($instance['heading']);
     $text = esc_attr($instance['text']);
    } else {
        $title = '';
        $heading = '';
        $text = '';
    }
    ?>

    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('heading'); ?>"><?php _e('Heading:'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('heading'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('heading'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $heading; ?>" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>"><?php _e('Text:'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></input>
    </p>

    <?php

    }

    // widget update
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        /* ... */
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['text'] = strip_tags($new_instance['text']);
        $instance['textarea'] = strip_tags($new_instance['textarea']);

        return $instance;
    }

    // widget display
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        /* ... */
        extract($args);

        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
        $heading = $instance['heading'];
        $text = $instance['text'];

        echo $before_widget;

         // Check if title is set
        if ( $title ) {
          echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        }

        if($heading) {
            echo '<h1>'.$heading.'</h1>';
        }

        // Check if text is set
        if( $text ) {
            echo '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
        }

        echo $after_widget;     
    }   
}
```

I think there's something wrong with the form function but I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to display the Widget in your index.php page, or the page you need?

```
<?php if(is_active_sidebar('showcase')) : ?>
     <?php dynamic_sidebar('showcase'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Yes I have this in my code and all the other widgets work perfectly fine with the sidebar. However, the widget I custom created doesn't even show up in the list let alone be able to add to the sidebar. Thanks anyway

Comment: Actually, I have the same problem. The code I wrote here was missing from me I thought that was the issue but after I added this code still not working for me. I will keep trying and searching for a solution. Let me know if you find something.